# Why it is possible to assign partial methods to delegates in spite of other constraints?

Tags: c#, partial-methods

I know the title might not be totally clear, but I didn't want to make it too long.

One thing boggles me when thinking about restrictions placed on partial methods. It seems to me that the rules are inconsistent. As you probably know:

> Partial methods must always have a return type of void, and they
>   cannot have any parameters  marked with the out modifier. These
>   restrictions are in place because at run time, the method  may not
>   exist and so you can’t initialize a variable to what the method might
>   return because  the method might not exist. Similarly, you can’t have
>   an out parameter because the method  would have to initialize it and
>   the method might not exist. [1]

It sounds sensible to me. But at the same time:

> If there is no implementing partial method declaration, then you
>   cannot have any code that  attempts to create a delegate that refers
>   to the partial method. Again, the reason is that the  method doesn’t
>   exist at run time. [1]

At first, all these rules seem to follow the same compiler logic. There is a difference, though. As stated in the second quotation, compiler issues an error only when there is no method implementation of the partial method. Why can't it also check for the implementation at compile-time in other scenarios? This would allow much more flexibility when using partial methods and the logic behind all rules would be identical.

I am afraid that the only answer I can get is "Because that's how it was implemented", but maybe there is something more to it?

[1] *CLR via C#, Fourth Edition*

Comment: My guess is that the first case exists to restrict the person who created the defining partial method declaration so that they cannot assume it is implemented. However the second case exists to allow the implementer who wrote the implementing partial method declaration to use it like any other method. You should not expect to be able to create a delegate for a partial method unless you are the implementer.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of partial methods is to facilitate extensibility in generated code scenarios without runtime performance impact. The code generator emits a partial method signature, and then emits code that calls this partial method.

Now, at compile time, if the method isn't implemented, these call sites get entirely removed, and the remaining code *has* to be valid. The quotes are confusing in this regard, because they're talking about *"runtime existence"* of the method. That's nonsense: everything is resolved at compile time.

This is the reason for the difference: the rules you quoted first impose restrictions on the method **signature**, whereas the delegate rule imposes a restriction on method **usage**.

The rules about the signature make sure you can call the method in a manner the code will remain valid if the method call is removed. And the intended use case for partial methods is for them to be absent **99% of the time**. If you require them to be implemented then *that's not the feature you should be using in the first place*. Use an abstract method or something alike.

Building a delegate to a method is like taking the pointer to the method, and you can't do that if the method doesn't exist (well, I suppose you could argue the compiler could just replace the delegate with `null` at this point, but you can't write, say, `new Action(null)`), yet there is no reason to disallow it if the method does exist, for the implementer's convenience. But the code generator shouldn't emit code that creates delegates to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the reason for partial methods is so they can be used in designer-generated code, i.e. the designer can generate calls to the methods and leave their (optional) implementation to a human developer (who will later compile the code). If, as you suggest, the calls gave compile-time errors when the method is not implemented, then there are cases where the **generated code** would not compile until the developer either changed the generated code (usually a bad idea) or until he implemented all the methods.

C# already has interfaces and abstract methods to force method implementation, partial methods try to do something else.